# How to model cycles between immutable class instances?

Tags: java, class-design

Immutable classes are great but there is one big problem i cant think of a sensible way to solve - cycles.

```
class Friend {
   Set<Friend> friends();
}
```

How does one model Me having You as a friend who in turn has me as a Friend back ?

**IMMUTABILITY**
This class from the outside world should definitely be immutable. The value held internally should be constant for the purposes of equality checks.

Comment: Do you know in advance all the bidirectional relationships you'll need, or are you adding them one at a time?  In the latter case, there's really no way to get the immutability guarantee, since you really are changing the objects.

Comment: In this case - no,, im trying to keep this simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[[[ Edit: Added code to demonstrate fully immutable concept ]]]

That's why builders are so nice for immutables - they allow mutability during construction to get everything set before you "freeze" it. In this case, I guess you need a Friend builder that supports creating cycles.

```
final FriendBuilder john = new FriendBuilder().setName("john");
final FriendBuilder mary = new FriendBuilder().setName("mary");
final FriendBuilder susan = new FriendBuilder().setName("susan");
john
  .likes(mary)
  .likes(susan);
mary
   .likes(susan)
   .likes(john);
susan
   .likes(john);

// okay lets build the immutable Friends
Map<Friend> friends = FriendsBuilder.createCircleOfFriends(john, mary, susan);
Friend immutableJohn = friends.get("john");
```

***Edit: Added immutable example below to demonstrate approach:***

- There was some discussion in the comments about whether an immutable version was possible.
- Fields are final and immutable. A modifiable set is used in the constructor, but it only the unmodifiable reference is kept after construction.
- I have another version that uses Guava ImmutableSet for a truly immutable set rather than JDK's unmodifiable wrapper.  It works the same, but uses Guava's nice set builder.

Code:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Note: potentially cycle graph - be careful of deep equals/hashCode/toString/etc.
 * Immutable
 */
public class Friend {

    public static class Builder {

        private final String name;
        private final Set<Builder> friends =
            new HashSet<Builder>();

        Builder(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Set<Builder> getFriends() {
            return friends;
        }

        void likes(final Builder... newFriends) {
            for (final Builder newFriend : newFriends)
            friends.add(newFriend);
        }

        public Map<String, Friend> createCircleOfFriends() {
            final IdentityHashMap<Builder, Friend> existing =
                new IdentityHashMap<Builder, Friend>();

            // Creating one friend creates the graph
            new Friend(this, existing);
            // after the call existingNodes contains all the nodes in the graph

            // Create map of the all nodes
            final Map<String, Friend> map =
                new HashMap<String, Friend>(existing.size(), 1f);
            for (final Friend current : existing.values()) {
                map.put(current.getName(), current);
            }

            return map;
        }
    }

    final String name;
    final Set<Friend> friends;

    private Friend(
            final Builder builder,
            final Map<Builder, Friend> existingNodes) {
        this.name = builder.getName();

        existingNodes.put(builder, this);

        final IdentityHashMap<Friend, Friend> friends =
            new IdentityHashMap<Friend, Friend>();
        for (final Builder current : builder.getFriends()) {
            Friend immutableCurrent = existingNodes.get(current);
            if (immutableCurrent == null) {
                immutableCurrent =
                    new Friend(current, existingNodes);
            }
            friends.put(immutableCurrent, immutableCurrent);
        }

        this.friends = Collections.unmodifiableSet(friends.keySet());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<Friend> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }


    /** Create string - prints links, but does not traverse them */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("Friend ").append(System.identityHashCode(this)).append(" {\n");
        sb.append("  name = ").append(getName()).append("\n");
        sb.append("  links = {").append("\n");
        for (final Friend friend : getFriends()) {
            sb
            .append("     ")
            .append(friend.getName())
            .append(" (")
            .append(System.identityHashCode(friend))
            .append(")\n");
        }
        sb.append("  }\n");
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Friend.Builder john = new Friend.Builder("john");
        final Friend.Builder mary = new Friend.Builder("mary");
        final Friend.Builder susan = new Friend.Builder("susan");
        john
          .likes(mary, susan);
        mary
           .likes(susan, john);
        susan
           .likes(john);

        // okay lets build the immutable Friends
        final Map<String, Friend> friends = john.createCircleOfFriends();

        for(final Friend friend : friends.values()) {
            System.out.println(friend);
        }

        final Friend immutableJohn = friends.get("john");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Node 11423854 {
  value = john
  links = {
     susan (19537476)
     mary (2704014)
  }
}
Node 2704014 {
  value = mary
  links = {
     susan (19537476)
     john (11423854)
  }
}
Node 19537476 {
  value = susan
  links = {
     john (11423854)
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to note that the builder pattern just hides the fact that you are doing post-construction initialization. The Friend class could not have a fully final structure for holding friends.

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik You can do this with a number of friends on the stack (diameter of the graph in best case, all in worst), and still keep immutability.

Comment: @Tom I don't buy it. Friend would have to have something non-final in order to eventually end up with two Friend objects referencing each other. A final reference to a proxy (aka builder) which is internally not final does not count. That's just another way of doing delayed initialization.

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik `class A { final B b; A() { this.b = new B(this); }} class B { final A a; B(A a) { this.a = a; }}` Well known stuff in functional languages, I believe.

Comment: @Tom - can that be generalized to @mP's example?

Comment: @Top - Ok that limited case does work, but I sure hope that no one writes code like that in practice.

Comment: @Konstantin - Perhaps you're right in general about `could not have a fully final structure`.  But I think you're making assumptions about how the relationships are being stored (i.e. as direct references).    If the relationships are stored as indexes, names, or another means of redirection, then the class certainly could be frozen.   Would it be worth using the indirection to get the fully final structure? Probably not, but I'm not going say you can't have final fields period if there was a forcing factor making it important enough to have them.

Comment: @Bert - Yes, you could use index/name. You would also have to make sure that whatever holds the mapping is immutable post initialization. After all, if the mapping can change, the effective object tree isn't really immutable. You would also have to be careful during entire initialization process to never resolve the reference as you could witness mutability due the mapping not being initialized at one point and initialized later.

Comment: @Konstantin - agreed - the structure being indexed into must also be immutable.  I was envisioning something like one of the Guava immutable classes. Since the `createCircleOfFriends()` method is creating a closed graph of friends, I can easily see creating this structure then. The `create` method is the point in time that everything gets frozen.  And I also agree to that this structure is write-only during construction, but I don't see why you would read it since the purpose is to create it.

Comment: @bert This might be the only way to do it. The fields arent final but from the outside instances of Friend look immutable. Will keep this open for a bit to gather more opinions. The interning+lookup capability of the builder i suppose is the best way to have singleton-like friend instances.

Comment: @Stephen C Sure, but this comment is probably a bit small.

Comment: @Stephen C - see edit for a generalized example of what Tom was saying.

Comment: @Konstantin - see edit for Friend class with fully final structure

Comment: @Bert F - that's not what I meant.  I'm not asking about the Builder approach.  I'm asking about a generalization of the approach in Tom Hawtin's comment ... in which everything is done in the constructors.

Comment: @Stephen C - I saw Tom's code as a demo that 2 immutable classes could refer to each other without the chicken-&-egg problem - by constructing another instance in the middle of constructing the 1st one. The constructor of the immutable class above generalizes this idea for more than just 2 nodes: it constructs more nodes in the middle of the constructing of the first one. The builder is just convenient wrapping for capturing the desired graph/relationships so it is not hard-coded as in Tom's example.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to model a cycle is with a [Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory). And a single source code line comment can be enough to enforce inmutability: "[can't touch this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otCpCn0l4Wo)".

What kind of inmutable enforcement are you looking for? Do you want a a velociraptor to appear [whenever you modify the inmutable Set](http://xkcd.com/292/)? The difference between `mutable` and `inmutable` is just a convention. However, the bits on the RAM can be easily modified and with the [Reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) you can break any encapsulation and data hiding conventions.

Ignoring the velociraptor for a moment, Java does not support an inmutable type. As a workaround, you need to model a datatype that behaves like one.

And for the inmutable property to make sense you need to make `Friend` an `interface`, having one implementing class: `InmutableFriend`, and the construction of the object should fully happen inside the constructor.

Then, since the graph contains cycles, before creating the final inmutable instances you need to store the graph nodes in some mutable temporary structure. You also need to return an [unmodifiableSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet%28java.util.Set%29) on the `InmutableFriend.friends()` method.

Finally, to clone the graph you need to implement a [Deep-copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy) algorithm like [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) on the Mutable graph. One question though is what happens when the graph is not [fully connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29).

```
interface Friend {
    public Set<Friend> friends();
}

class MutableFriend {
    private Set<MutableFriend> relations = new HashSet<MutableFriend>();

    void connect(MutableFriend otherFiend) {
        if (!relations.contains(otherFriend)) {
            relations.add(otherFiend);
            otherFriend.connect(this);
        }
    }

    Friend freeze() {
        Map<MutableFriend, InmutableFriend> table = ...;

        /*
         * FIXME: Implement a Breadth-first search to clone the graph,
         * using this node as the starting point.
         *
         * TODO: If the graph is not connected this won't work.
         *
         */
    }
}

class InmutableFriend() implements Friend {
    private Set<Friend> connections;

    public Set<Friend> friends() {
        return connections;
    }

    public InmutableFriend(Set<Friend> connections) {
        // Can't touch this.
        this.connections = Collections.unmodifiableSet(connections);
    }
}
```

Comment: The freezer pattern is really ugly imho, im starting to think that Friend will look immutable but deep inside the builder will add sttuff to it and then freeze, at which point it can be given to the outside world...

Comment: @mP: The freezer is not a pattern, It's an algorithm called Deep Copy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy

Comment: sorry mate i misread MutableFrield =Field:) ignore my original comment.

Comment: @mP: Anyway, if the programmer wants to break the inmutable class, he/she can do it using using the Reflection API.

Answer (score -1):

Immutability doesn't need to be compiler-enforced to be valid architecturaly. You can have a legitimate immutable object that takes post-construction initialization parameters. For instance...

```
private Object something;

public void init( final Object something )
{
   if( this.something != null )
   {
       throw new IllegalStateException();
   }

   this.something = something
}
```

The member field "something" isn't final, but it cannot be set more than once either.

A more complex variant based on discussion in comments...

```
private boolean initialized;
private Object a;
private Object b;

public void init( final Object a, final Object b )
{
   if( this.initialized )
   {
       throw new IllegalStateException();
   }

   this.initialized = true;
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
}

public Object getA()
{
   assertInitialized();
   return this.a;
}

public Object getB()
{
   assertInitialized();
   return this.b;
}

private void assertInitialized()
{
   if( this.initialized )
   {
       throw new IllegalStateException( "not initialized" );
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant: if (something == null)

Comment: Actually, I meant "if( this.something != null )". The if statement is there to catch attempt at setting something more than once.

Comment: The parts that concern me about this are (1) this "private" init method could mistakenly never gets called, and (2) this code won't work if `null` if a valid value for `something`.  If `null` is a valid value of `something`, then the initialization of `something` needs to be tracked in a separate flag.

Comment: @Bert - (1) is easily addressed by having other methods in the class fail if class is not initialized; (2) you already have indicate the solution. In more complex versions of this pattern, I typically see "initialized" boolean member tracking this state as there is typically more than one field being initialized.

Comment: @Konstantin - (1) Its absolutely addressable, at the cost of more complexity -  doing a am-i-fully-initialized check in every method. This is one of the reason I tend to shy away from this "partially initialized" pattern when possible.  (2) I thought it was worth pointing out the null issue and solution, so people using this pattern in practice would consider this case.

Comment: Your public init() method sux because its possible to call it twice in code on the same instance, even if at runtime there will be a failure.

Comment: @mP - Any solution to your question is going to be sub-optimal. There isn't an optimal solution. My solution has the benefit of being the simplest to implement and understand. Plus after initialization objects are referenced directly. The build/proxy solution doesn't have post construction initializer issue, but you have to write a proxy and then be always referencing objects through it. More complex. Harder to prove correct. Pluses and minuses in both solutions. In practice, I see the initializer pattern far more than I see the builder/proxy pattern. Take from that what you will.

Comment: @KK Your prolly right but there are ways that have less problems than others while achieving the final objective.